# Multiple welcome pages in Team Foundation Server 2015

Tags: tfs, markdown, tfs-2015

We're using TFS 2015 Update 1 and have just noticed the 'welcome pages' feature. I've seen a few screenshots of this feature being used where a Team Project can have multiple .md files in it's root and they all appear in the left hand navigation off the welcome page. However, I don't seem to be able to get multiple menu items to appear, no matter how many .md files I add into the root of the Team Project.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this?

thanks!

Comment: I'm not certain but I think they removed that functionality.  I believe you have to simply add links to your additional files within readme.md so essentially create a table of contents in your readme.md.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately ，it doesn't currently work, **the feature has been removed**.

> We have made some recent design changes, which reserved the left pane
>   for repository navigation for Git projects. We will be rolling out a
>   change soon to introduce a Table of Contents on the welcome page,
>   which will pick up other markdown files in your root directory.
>
> In the meantime, a workaround is to provide a relative link to your
>   other file from README.md or use the Code Hub to view a tree of the
>   files.
>
> *Thanks, Yi-Wei Ang, Program Manager - Visual Studio Online*
>
> Source:[Other .md files not appearing on welcome page](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/1055798)